# Small exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s with symmetries

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

*Definition:* An exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a smooth open 4-manifold $E\mathbb{R}^4$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ but not diffeomorphic to it.

*Definition:* An exotic $E\mathbb{R}^4$ is called **small** if it can be smoothly embedded as an open subset of the standard $\mathbb{R}^4$. We can assume that $E\mathbb{R}^4$ is an open inside of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

*Question:* Is there exist a small exotic $E\mathbb{R}^4\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ which is invariant by the antipode map?

By antipode map I mean the map whose sends $x$ to $-x$.

Comment: Why not? You can take two copies of a small exotic $R^4$ and perform the end-connected sum along "the same" proper ray. I think, it will give you the required example, but I did not think through the details.